# Django Raw Query

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
lists = []
lists = cursor.execute(
    "select a.employee_id,a.first_name,"
    "c.breakfast_count, b.lunch_count,"
    "d.dinner_count from qpscsmas_employee_details a,"
    "qpscsmas_emp_lunch b,"
    "qpscsmas_emp_breakfast c,"
    "qpscsmas_emp_dinner d "
    "where a.rfidcardno = %s "
    "and b.rfidcardno = %s "
    "and c.rfidcardno = %s "
    "and d.rfidcardno = %s,"
    "['s','s','s','s']"
)
print lists
```

The above query is giving me an empty list.

The problem with this is that it is not showing any error also.

It is working fine in MySQL when i am giving the exact values in place of the parameters

Comment: what exactly your problem is ???

Comment: My problem is that i am unable to pass the parameters, more specifically i need the way to use parameters in the querey.

I am attaching the querey which was working fine.
cursor.execute(select a.employee_id,a.first_name, c.breakfast_count, b.lunch_count, d.dinner_count from qpscsmas_employee_details a,qpscsmas_emp_lunch b,qpscsmas_emp_breakfast c, qpscsmas_emp_dinner d where a.rfidcardno = '7b5c7f45' and b.rfidcardno = '7b5c7f45' and c.rfidcardno = '7b5c7f45' and d.rfidcardno = '7b5c7f45')

Answer (score 1):

First you need to remove the double quotes from your parameters list and separate it with comma from your query string, e.g.:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
```

After you executed the query you need to fetch the rows, see [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly). You may fetch the next one (`cursor.fetchone()`) or fetch all rows (`cursor.fetchall()`).

Examples:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

This cleaned up query should work:

```
cursor.execute(
    "select a.employee_id,a.first_name,"
    "c.breakfast_count, b.lunch_count,"
    "d.dinner_count from qpscsmas_employee_details a,"
    "qpscsmas_emp_lunch b,"
    "qpscsmas_emp_breakfast c,"
    "qpscsmas_emp_dinner d "
    "where a.rfidcardno = %s "
    "and b.rfidcardno = %s "
    "and c.rfidcardno = %s "
    "and d.rfidcardno = %s", 
    ['s','s','s','s']
)
```

Comment: i did the same but it did not returned any data. That's why i am asking that the way i have passed the parameters is it the correct way?

Comment: Remove the double quotes from your parameters list.

Comment: Okay , This may work for the single parameter , but what would happen if the parameters are more than one. Give some example in which more than one parameters are used.

Comment: I added your query in my answer.

Comment: I need to clarify one thing the code u are seeing above is not the one i posted. That was being edited.
Orignal code is as: cursor.execute("select a.employee_id,a.first_name, c.breakfast_count, b.lunch_count, d.dinner_count from qpscsmas_employee_details a,qpscsmas_emp_lunch b,qpscsmas_emp_breakfast c, qpscsmas_emp_dinner d where a.rfidcardno = %s and b.rfidcardno = %s and c.rfidcardno = %s and d.rfidcardno = %s",['s','s','s','s'])

Comment: My test with this query `cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM django_content_type WHERE app_label = %s or model = %s", ["auth", "session"])` is completely fine and returns the desired results. Perhaps your conditions do not match any rows?

Comment: lists = []
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  listz = employee_details.objects.all()
  for i in listz:
   print i.rfidcardno // its printing
cursor.execute("select a.employee_id,a.first_name, c.breakfast_count, b.lunch_count, d.dinner_count from qpscsmas_employee_details a,qpscsmas_emp_lunch b,qpscsmas_emp_breakfast c, qpscsmas_emp_dinner d where a.rfidcardno = %s and b.rfidcardno = %s and c.rfidcardno = %s and d.rfidcardno = %s",["i.rfidcardno","i.rfidcardno","i.rfidcardno","i.rfidcardno"])
   lists.append(cursor.fetchone())
  print lists
  for i in lists:
   print i
Its returning empty list

Comment: cursor.execute("select a.employee_id,a.first_name, c.breakfast_count, b.lunch_count, d.dinner_count from qpscsmas_employee_details a,qpscsmas_emp_lunch b,qpscsmas_emp_breakfast c, qpscsmas_emp_dinner d where a.rfidcardno = %s and b.rfidcardno = %s and c.rfidcardno = %s and d.rfidcardno = %s",[s,s,s,s])


It will work properly.